# calendar time stored as a signed 32-bit integer - when will it overflow

Tags: c, unix, time-t, year2038

I'm going through exercises from Advanced Programming in Unix and encountered the following question:

*If the calendar time is stored as a signed 32-bit integer, in which year will it overflow?*

positive signed integer = 2147483647

In the following calculation I'm not accounting for leap years:

```
((((2147483647 / 60sec) /60min)/24)/365) = 68.1yrs
```

This is a naive approach. How can I approach this question professionally?

The following solution presented earlier by a stack member was very helpful to print out the year.

```
int epoch_time = INT_MAX;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time_t epoch_time_as_time_t = epoch_time;
timeinfo = localtime(&epoch_time_as_time_t);
printf("2] overflow date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
```

Comment: For me your approach is correct.

Comment: @MichaelWalz it's not exactly correct as it uses 365 days per year, in reality the figure is 365.242...

Comment: Are you assuming a particular epoch? There is the standard unix epoch, but you can use some other epoch if you want.

Comment: This is known as the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). I have a whole talk about it called [REPENT, FOR THE END OF THE UNIX EPOCH IS NIGH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQFZ_MPTVpc&list=PLftoH6vx4SjkMEmPVG4bBem_vg4F0T7oD&index=1)! (Apologies for the bad audio)

Comment: @M.M I wrote _the approach is correct_ and the OP stated that he didn't account for leap years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when will it overflow

Assuming that on the platform in question `int` is 32 bits wide (and `time_t` is an *integral* type, will say it's not a `struct` for example), just do

```
printf("%s\n", asctime(localtime(&(time_t){difftime(INT_MAX, 0)})));
```

and you know.

It prints:

```
Tue Jan 19 04:14:07 2038
```

---

Exchanging the arguments to `difftime()` one gets the "earliest" date possible, BTW:

```
printf("%s\n", asctime(localtime(&(time_t){difftime(0, INT_MAX)})));
```

prints

```
Fri Dec 13 21:45:53 1901
```

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to use the UNIX `date` command.  Specifically, `date -d '@<seconds>'` will output the date and time corresponding to `<seconds>` seconds since the UNIX epoch.  Additionally, you can provide the format specifier `+%Y` if you just care about the year.

So, for this example you would execute

```
date -d '@2147483647' +%Y
```

and would see the output `2038`.

Comment: The epoch is Jan 1, 1970 so if I add the result of my calculation the overflow date would be 2038.

Answer (score 3):

The approach may look naive, but is almost accurate. You need to take leap years and maybe leap seconds into account.

The Wikipedia page on UNIX time mentions the year 2038 somewhere. There you find the remaining details.